# Hide images until they're loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, image-loading

I got a jQuery script which is dinamically appending data to the "holder" at some timeinterval. The data looks like this:

```
<div class="item-box etc etc"> <img src="data.png"> </div>
```

and I'm loading like 50 images at once, my goal is to make them `fadeIn`, when each image is loaded.

I've tried the following:

```
parentDiv.on("load", "img", function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeIn(500);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ESUm/2/

but seems that `on` method doesn't have `load` or `ready` methods. I ran out of ideas.

Comment: Are you sure you're not attaching the listener after the image has already loaded?

Comment: you should choose an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just set the onload property when you add the image.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "some url"
img.onload=function(){$(img).fadeIn(500);}
document.getElementByID('parent').appendChild(img);
```

see working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3ESUm/3/)

Comment: This won't really work if I'm loading the elements dinamically. See the presented fiddle.

Comment: Check the updated answer. I provide a working fiddle.

Comment: using `fadeIn(500)` for displaying the image is a poor choice... it would add an additional 500 ms before showing the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your images in first-loaded-first displayed order like this:

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/7w6cb/

```
var imageURLs=[];
var imgs=[];
imageURLs.push("house100x100.png");
imageURLs.push("house32x32.png");
imageURLs.push("house16x16.png");

for(var i=0;i<imageURLs.length;i++){

    imgs.push(document.createElement("img"));
    imgs[i].onload=function(){
        var id=this.myId;
        this.id=id;           
        document.body.appendChild(this);
        $("#"+id).hide().fadeIn(1500);
    }
    imgs[i].myId=i;
    imgs[i].src=imageURLs[i];
}
```